# Best practices of creating a filesystem representation on the frontend

Tags: reactjs, database, frontend, filesystems, backend

I want to create a web interface for a folder structure on my server. Basically like dropbox or any other cloud storage but only with read functionality, no creation of new files or uploading.

I'm wondering what the best way would be to create a "virtual" representation of an existing folder structure on my server.

My idea was to recursively loop through the directory on the server and create a database entry for every file or folder. I'd create a hash of every file to uniquely identify them.

Like this:

```
'1382b6993e9f270cb1c29833be3f5750': {
    type: 'folder',
    name: 'root',
    path: '/',
    parentPath: null,
    parentID: null,
    children: ['147d0ef33fe657ce53a83de6a630473d']
  },
'147d0ef33fe657ce53a83de6a630473d': {
    type: 'folder',
    name: 'pictures',
    parentID: '1382b6993e9f270cb1c29833be3f5750',
    parentPath: '/',
    path: '/pictures',
    children: ['8f7c5959dbb088c0aef8b145dbdf6e43']
  },
'8f7c5959dbb088c0aef8b145dbdf6e43': {
    type: 'file',
    name: 'cat.jpg',
    parentID: '147d0ef33fe657ce53a83de6a630473d',
    parentPath: '/pictures',
    path: '/pictures/cat.jpg'
  },
```

To account for changes in the directory I'd periodically run a process to scan it and update the database accordingly.

It should be said that the directory is rather big with many subfolders and hundreds of files.

Since the whole folder structure is rather big I could see it being a problem to keep the whole tree in the react state, but I guess that could be fixed by always fetching the directory contents when navigating on the frontend.

Does this approach make sense or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either optimize the disk usage or the CPU usage based on what is more convenient for you. It is just a tradeoff between the two in the end.

If you want to maximize your CPU load and know that disk space is cheap, you can store the content of your entire filesystem's tree representation like you did and make periodic updates. The main pro is that you will have a very little CPU footprint and if your app is used by many users, your server won't be overloaded by API requests. The main cons is that is takes a lot of CPU and disk usage once in a while when you need to periodically update your filesystem's tree and you may have synchronization issues (when a file has been created but not stored in the database).

In the database aspect of things, a high-readonly purpose database should be constructed using NoSQL database instead of SQL database when there is little to no relations between data and/or you want fast read access to them in a large scale.

If you want to stick to SQL databases, you should be using a foreign key for storing the parent folder such as when creating a database entry for a file, you can do something similar.

```sql
INSERT INTO files(path, type, parent) VALUES("/home/johndoe", "FOLDER", 987126398726387)
```

Where `987126398726387` would be the `id` column of a `files` row related to the `/home` folder for instance. That way your reconciliation folder's algorithm will be very simple since you will only make a single request to retrieve all files for a folder.

```sql
SELECT * FROM files WHERE parent = 987126398726387;
```

And you can use all the power of your SQL to order, group and do the stuff that you might want to do there.

Instead of loading your disk usage, you can trade disk usage for more CPU usage by completely removing your database and having a single API endpoint that looks like `https://api.com/folders/:tree`, where `tree` is the folder's tree requested by the client.

For instance, if I start the application, I'll probably want to request the `https://api.com/folders/` endpoint, and you can send only the content of that folder without its subfolder, thus removing the need for a recursive algorithm. Then, if I need to go in the `/home` folder, I can call the `https://api.com/folders/home` endpoint. Then, I'll go in the `/home/johndoe` folder with `https://api.com/folders/home/johndoe`, and in the `/home/johndoe/code` folder with `https://api.com/folders/home/johndoe/code`, etc...

You can even pass the requested path in the body of your asynchronous HTTP request from the client instead.

```
GET /folders HTTP/2
Host: api.com
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "path": "/home/johndoe/code"
}
```

You can display a loader while you are updating the current folder on the client side while the API respond. This will obviously make much more API calls but you save a lot of disk usage by doing that. And if you need speed or less CPU usage, you can use a compiled language like V, Go or Rust for that and make a microservice that the sole purpose is to get the content of a folder fast.

Comment: Thanks for your very elaborated answer! 

I should've said that I need the database entries of all files, because I want to be able to add tags to them and view them in other ways than the folder structure. 

Therefore I'm stuck with using a database or is there a middle way I dont think of?

Comment: Is your database SQL or NoSQL?

Comment: I planned to use a SQLite database since the tool wont be used by many users concurrently and to be able to deploy it as single binary that creates its own database file.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make a quick suggestion on the type of database you might want to use, even though you might start with a simple SQLite database first.

Comment: Would you have two tables for files and folders or just one combined table, with the type property discerning between file and folder? I would think that having two seperated tables is easier to understand but one table makes it easier to query without needing joins.

Comment: Files and folders both have a very similar set of properties and it would only increase the load on the database to have two separate tables with almost the same properties. If you really want to have one (or more) properties alongside the similar properties that are different from a file and a folder, you should probably use the concept of [Generalization/Specialization](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-specialization-and-generalization-in-dbms).

Comment: For instance, you would have an `abstract_files` table that has a size and a path, a `files` table that can have a `mode` like `execute`, `read` or `write` (though this example is dumb since a folder can also have it but bear with me) and a `abstract_file_id` that points to a `abstract_files` table, and a `folder` table that belongs to an `abstract_files` through an `abstract_file_id` column and that can have a relationship between 0 or more `files`. This means less redundant informations compared to having two tables that almost have the same columns thus saving some bytes.

Comment: What would be a good way to uniquely identify a folder? I cant create a hash from it and the folder name itself might not be unique. I also cant use the path as a primary key since with files I want to use the hash. When I use a random UUID, there will be a new entry of the same folder when I re run the script.

Comment: You could first split the path and then checking if you have an entry in your database that already matches the path. For instance, for the path `/home/user/code/index.php` you would have to first check for `home`, then `user` (with the parent `home`), then `code` (with the parent `user`) and finally `index.php` (with the parent `code`). Although it might overload your database with many requests if your filesystem is huge. Hashes makes a good choice for reducing the time and space complexity of this algorithm.